# References to part of a page

Tags: reference

Is there any traditional manner of reference to a particular part of a page?
p. 55, above, p. 30, below, p. 39, middle?
Has it been customary to use Latin for this?
(Cf. German: oben, unten, mitte.)

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/298687/how-to-abbreviate-the-bottom-or-to-top-of-a-page

Comment: I believe the Encyclopaedia Britannica, in its last print edition of 30 volumes with two columns per page, used letters a-h to indicate quarters of each column (eg p315e would be the top quarter of the second column). But I've not seen that system anywhere else.

Comment: In English, _above_ and _below_ have a special meaning when referencing parts of a text: they are relative to the reader’s current position, with _above_ meaning “coming earlier in the text than where you are now” and _below_ the opposite. So they definitely don’t work here. You would use _top_ and _bottom_ instead. @AndrewLeach Thank heavens for that. What an absolutely ridonkulous system.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet With the printed Encyclopaedia Britannica (before google), it's quite useful to have an indication of where on the page to look.

Comment: @Lawrence Yes, but a saner system would be preferable. Though I think I may have misread _quarters_ as _quadrants_ back in July when I commented. I remember wondering why anyone would ever need to refer to the left or right half of a single column. Still, something like “p. 315-R1” (for ‘right column, first quarter’) would be easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Always include the page number, unless on the same page.  You can count the paragraphs, use first or last paragraph and even count the sentences in each paragraph.  Sometimes it is helpful to refer to the text in said paragraph (but this is rather lengthy unless you intend to refer the reader to the text instead of rewriting the entire paragraph. This all assumes the document keeps page breaks when printed so watch out you don't reference something that might move from one page to another.  Some word editors can keep track of this automatically and adjust the reference in a field.